# Count number of rows in another table in a VIEW

Tags: mysql, sql

So I'm trying to count the number of times where the `client_id` appears in another table from their id. This is what i got:

```
CREATE VIEW `client_list` AS
SELECT
    `client`.id,
    `client`.name,
    `client`.email,
    `build`.COUNT(*) AS quantity
FROM (
        `client`
        JOIN `build` ON `client`.id = `build`.client_id
);
```

And the error i get is from my syntax.

These are both the creation of the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `build` (
  `build_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `client_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
  `date` DATE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`build_id`)
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE `client` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
CREATE VIEW `client_list` AS
SELECT
    `client`.id,
    `client`.name,
    `client`.email,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `build`) AS quantity
FROM (
    `client`
    JOIN `build` ON `client`.id = `build`.client_id
);
```